# Moxy: List of objects XML and JSON can't get both look good

Tags: xml, json, inheritance, jaxb, moxy

I have a problem getting Moxy to generate "good" XML and JSON for a list of inherited objects. Either of the XML looks find or the JSON looks fine, but not at the same time. Here is the model:

```
public static abstract class Animal {
    private String name;

    protected Animal() {
    }
    protected Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
@XmlRootElement
public static class Tiger extends Animal {
    public Tiger() {
    }
    public Tiger(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public static class Lion extends Animal {
    public Lion() {
    }
    public Lion(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public static class Zoo {
    private List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

    @XmlElementRef
    public List<Animal> getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }
    public void setAnimals(List<Animal> animals) {
        this.animals = animals;
    }
    public void addAnimal(Animal a) {
        animals.add(a);
    }
}
```

The XML and JSON generated from the following Zoo instance

```
    zoo = new Zoo();
    zoo.addAnimal(new Tiger("Hobbes"));
    zoo.addAnimal(new Lion("Simba"));
    zoo.addAnimal(new Tiger("Sherikan"));
```

Look like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <zoo>
     <tiger>
        <name>Hobbes</name>
     </tiger>
     <lion>
        <name>Simba</name>
     </lion>
     <tiger>
        <name>Sherikan</name>
     </tiger>
  </zoo>
  {
     "zoo" : {
        "tiger" : [ {
           "name" : "Hobbes"
        }, {
           "name" : "Sherikan"
        } ],
        "lion" : [ {
           "name" : "Simba"
        } ]
     }
  }
```

The XML looks exactly what I want it too, but the JSON is weird. The way that the Moxy uses the type as key does not preserve order among the elements in the list. Is this a bug or feature?

If I change the annotation on `Zoo.animals` to `@XmlElement` the JSON output looks fine, but the XML output has changed to something that I can't use.

```
  {
     "zoo" : {
        "animals" : [ {
           "type" : "tiger",
           "name" : "Hobbes"
        }, {
           "type" : "lion",
           "name" : "Simba"
        }, {
           "type" : "tiger",
           "name" : "Sherikan"
        } ]
     }
  }
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <zoo>
     <animals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="tiger">
        <name>Hobbes</name>
     </animals>
     <animals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="lion">
        <name>Simba</name>
     </animals>
     <animals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="tiger">
        <name>Sherikan</name>
     </animals>
  </zoo>
```

The only way I've come up with to solve this is to create an external OXM binding file to override the annotation on `Zoo.animals`. The binding below is registered using the property of JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xml-accessor-type="PUBLIC_MEMBER" xml-accessor-order="ALPHABETICAL"
                xml-mapping-metadata-complete="false"
                package-name="com.example">
     <java-types>
        <java-type name="com.example.JAXBTest2$Zoo">
           <java-attributes>
              <xml-element java-attribute="animals"/>
           </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
     </java-types>
  </xml-bindings>
```

Is there a better solution to this that doesn't use an external binding file?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group

> The way that the Moxy uses the type as key does not preserve order
>   among the elements in the list. Is this a bug or feature?

We did that on purpose to prevent the key from being repeated.

> The only way I've come up with to solve this is to create an external
>   OXM binding file to override the annotation on Zoo.animals. The
>   binding below is registered using the property of
>   JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE.

This is how I would recommend solving your use case.

Comment: Blaise, thanks for your quick response. Do you know the reason for storing type info in the json keys instead of a synthetic type property in the actual object?