# JAXB for lists to be returned naturally for JSON or XML

Tags: java, xml, json, moxy

I'm using MOXy with Jersey to implement a RESTful API and want to return lists naturally for JSON and XML, by which I mean that the XML contains an element tag for the overall collection as well as the collection items, whereas the JSON contains a tag for the collection only.

For example, I want to return an "organisation" resource with nested lists of facilities and locations.  As XML:

```
<organisation>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>XYZ</name>
  <facilities>
    <facility>
      <id>1</id>
      <text>Telephone</text>
    </facility>
    <facility>
      <id>3</id>
      <text>Whiteboard</text>
    </facility>
  </facilities>
  <locations>
    <location>
      <id>1</id>
      <kind>REGION</kind>
      <name>London</name>
    </location>
    <location>
      <id>2</id>
      <kind>REGION</kind>
      <name>Manchester</name>
    </location>
  </locations>
</organisation>
```

And as JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "XYZ",
  "facilities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Telephone"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Whiteboard"
    }
  ],
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "kind": "REGION",
      "name": "London"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "kind": "REGION",
      "name": "Manchester"
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to get a code base that allows me to return the output like this for both XML and JSON. If I use a class to wrap the nested list, then the XML appears correct but not the JSON (see "ExternalFacilities" below). If I define the nested list as an `ArrayList` sub-class then the JSON appears correct but not the XML (see "ExternalLocations" below).

**XML sample showing "facilities" list correct but not "locations"**

See that there is no XML element that wraps the "locations" list (as there is for "facilities"), and also that each location has a pluralised element name.

```
<organisation>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>XYZ</name>
  <facilities>
    <facility>
      <id>1</id>
      <text>Telephone</text>
    </facility>
    <facility>
        <id>3</id>
        <text>Whiteboard</text>
    </facility>
  </facilities>
  <locations>
    <id>1</id>
    <kind>REGION</kind>
    <name>London</name>
  </locations>
  <locations>
    <id>2</id>
    <kind>REGION</kind>
    <name>Manchester</name>
  </locations>
</organisation>
```

**JSON sample showing "locations" list correct but not "facilities"**

See that the "facilities" list is a JSON object containing a JSON array, whereas I just want the JSON array (with the pluralised element name).

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "XYZ",
  "facilities": {
    "facility": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Telephone"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "Whiteboard"
        }
    ]
  },
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "kind": "REGION",
      "name": "London"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "kind": "REGION",
      "name": "Manchester"
    }
  ]
}
```

This samples above are produced using the same code, just changing the Accept HTTP header to have Jersey return JSON instead of XML. Here is an excerpt of the classes:

**ExternalOrganisation.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="organisation")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExternalOrganisation {

   private String             name;
   private ExternalFacilities facilities;
   private ExternalLocations  locations;

   ...

}
```

**ExternalFacilities.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="facilities")
public class ExternalFacilities {
  @XmlElementRef
  private List<ExternalFacility> list;
  ...
}
```

**ExternalLocations.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="locations")
public class ExternalLocations extends ArrayList<ExternalLocation> {
  ...
}
```

**ExternalFacility.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="facility")
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "uri", "kind", "text"})
public class ExternalFacility extends ExternalBase {
    // id inherited
    private String text;
    ....
}
```

**ExternalLocation.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="location")
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "kind", "name"})
public class ExternalLocation extends ExternalBase {
    // id inherited
    @XmlElement private LocationKind kind;
    @XmlElement private String       name;
    ...
}
```

Seems at first similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569891/moxy-list-of-objects-xml-and-json-cant-get-both-look-good) but I'm not trying to mix the types of object in my lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following to get the desired XML and JSON representations:

### Step #1 - Leverage `@XMLElementWrapper`

Instead of:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="organisation")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExternalOrganisation {

   private String             name;
   private ExternalFacilities facilities;
   private ExternalLocations  locations;

   ...

}
```

You could do the following with `@XmlElementWrapper` (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="organisation")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ExternalOrganisation {

   private String             name;

   @XmlElementWrapper
   @XmlElementRef
   private List<ExternalFacility> facilities;

   @XmlElementWrapper
   @XmlElementRef
   private List<ExternalLocation>  locations;

   ...

}
```

### Step #2 - Leverage MOXy's Wrapper as Array Name Property

By specifying the wrapper as array name property, MOXy will use the value from `@XmlElementWrapper` as the JSON array name.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class YourApplication  extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(1);
        set.add(YourService.class);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        MOXyJsonProvider moxyJsonProvider = new MOXyJsonProvider();
        moxyJsonProvider.setWrapperAsArrayName(true);

        HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(1);
        set.add(moxyJsonProvider);
        return set;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/binding-to-json-xml-handling-collections.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxy-is-new-default-json-binding.html

Comment: I was reading your blog posts earlier but didn't come across these ones. I've tried this and got it to work, however I found that instead of using `@XmlElementWrapper @XmlElementRef`, I had to specify `@XmlElementWrapper @XmlElement(name="facility")`, in order to get both the XML and JSON right. Perhaps there's something else I'm doing wrong, but I'm happy with this solution. I've read a lot of your answers on Stack Overflow, so thanks not just for this answer but for all the others that have proved informative and helpful.

Comment: I've subsequently noticed that whilst this approach works when the sub-classed lists (such as `ExternalFacilities`) work when they are elements of another `XmlRootElement` object (such as `ExternalOrganisation` above), they don't work when passed back as the JAX-RS response entity. Is that expected?

Comment: Is there any property for this? Using `getProperties()`?