# JAXB: XML and JSON don't work together

Tags: rest, jaxb, moxy

I have the same problem as posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890731/jaxb-for-lists-to-be-returned-naturally-for-json-or-xml) question. However the answer of this question doesn't solve my problem, because I'm not returning a list of objects but a `Response` and in the response I'm putting the list.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @MickaëlB, if you read the question I've provided the link to, you will understand exactly what I'm asking. The only difference is, as I've stated in my question, I'm putting the list in a `Response` and returning the `Response`. I didn't want to repeat the question, that's why I only provided the link to that question.